# Rigid Body Doesn't Interact

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm creating a simulation of the 9/11 tragedy. However, the rigid body for both building and the plane don't seem to work at all. Plus, the plane itself is rotating every time I add rigid body to it. Does anyone know why? Although the plane hits the building, both don't seem to interact, the plane goes through the building and the building doesn't get destroyed.